# Windows Metro: links in img tag won't work

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing an app in Metro using HTML+Javascript. My links are not working when they are used to create a link in a img tag:

```
<h4><a href="/pages/childpage.html">Go to child page</a></h4>
<a href="/pages/childpage.html"><img src="/images/home/child.jpg" /></a>
```

The first link works OK and the second does not. When I click the image, it blocks the app.

For the links, I'm using a Application.PageControlNavigator [as suggested in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx). My JS has:

```
(function () {
   "use strict"; 

   function linkClickEventHandler(eventInfo) {
       eventInfo.preventDefault();
       var link = eventInfo.target;
       WinJS.Navigation.navigate(link.href);
   }

   WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
       ready: function (element, options) {
           WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", linkClickEventHandler, false);
           WinJS.UI.processAll();
       }
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the link.href returns the src string instead of the href string when having the tag  used inside the tag . In your case the link.href returns "/images/home/child.jpg". I asssume this is a bug and not a feature. The workaround is not to use the href.link.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

Use the onclick property of the `<a>` tag and call a handler() function as shown below:

```
<a onclick="handler();"><img src="/images/home/child.png" /></a>
```

Body of the handler function is as shown below:

```
function handler()
{
     WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/childpage.html');
}
```

Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

By blocks, I assume you mean "hang"? Is it calling your linkClickEventHandler when you click the image?

Comment: Yes, I put a message box there. It's calling. I did a workaround binding the link in the div, and getting rid of the "a".